# How to trace RPC between two docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers, cloud, trace, rpc

Suppose I run a `server` in `container1` and a `client` in `container2`. `client` invokes an RPC function in `server`. How can I trace this RPC invocation?

I know there are some distributed tracing systems, but most need manual instrumentation. I want to trace the RPCs no matter what application runs in the container(i.e., the application may not be instrumented). My naive idea is to trace RPC communication between docker containers. Is there any solution?